# Oracle 10gR2 CLOB Data type

Tags: oracle10g

I am having table with clob column & trying to insert SIGNED character data which contains =176048 characters, it throws error has Insert exception data transaction java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01704: string literal too long

Answer (score 1):

From [this AskTom answer](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1019631214472):

> Yes, you can insert upto 4000 bytes in an INSERT statement -- just
>
> insert into t ( clob_col ) values ( 'Hello World' );
>
> it works.  For larger chunks, you
>   would insert an EMPTY_CLOB() and then
>   using that newly  created lob locator
>   write to it in chunks.  It would look
>   like this:
>
> ```
> begin
>   insert into t ( clob_col ) values ( empty_clob() )
>   returning clob_col into Local_Variable;
>
>   dbms_lob.write( local_variable, .... );
>
> end; 
> /
> ```
>
> in plsql.

Answer (score 0):

You can only insert string literals of at most 4000 characters.  Otherwise you need to use a bind variable.